Getting 503 Service Unavailable error when uploading data to BigQuery in Python
Problem Description:
I am trying to upload data to Google BigQuery using Python. The data is successfully fetched from an API and processed, but I consistently encounter a 503 Service Unavailable error when attempting to upload the data to BigQuery. I’ve already checked the following:

My BigQuery quotas are fine, and I’m not exceeding any limits.
My internet connection is stable.
I’ve implemented a retry logic in the Python code, but the issue persists after several retries.

What I Tried:

Implemented a retry mechanism with exponential backoff, but still encountering the same error.
Checked my BigQuery quotas and account status, and everything seems normal.
Reduced the size of data uploads to test if it was related to large payloads, but no success.

Observed Error Message:
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/...: Service Unavailable

I successfully fetched stock data from the Polygon.io API and calculated several technical indicators using Python.
After that, I attempted to upload the results to BigQuery for further analysis.
I implemented retry logic in the Python script to handle temporary service outages, but despite multiple retries, I continue to encounter the 503 Service Unavailable error. (2 days same issue)
I also reduced the batch size of uploads to see if smaller datasets would succeed, but the error persists.
I'm expecting the data to be successfully uploaded to my BigQuery table without hitting the 503 Service Unavailable error.


Can you share your code?
